# QuickFill/flood fill algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, graphics, flood-fill

I need a flood fill algorithm to fill existing raster shapes with various colors and fill patterns. From what I know, the QuickFill algorithm is the best way to do a flood fill. I've found a number of implementations, but they are all in C++ and use Windows SDK functions. The problem is that I need a .NET implementation.

If worse comes to worse I can write a new implementation, but I would rather use an existing implementation (that hopefully doesn't have bugs). Is anyone aware of an existing flood fill implementation in C#/VB.NET?

Comment: Are you talking about _the_ `System.Drawing.Graphics` .NET class?

Comment: Beemer, I would like to use types in the Graphics class, but I didn't find any flood fill types, unless you have an existing graphics path. I am dealing with raster images, so no luck there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like a lot to work with the [Aforge Library](http://www.aforgenet.com/) that has two good FlodFill implementations, but both are 4 directional only.

If you need other implementations there exist two code project articles [Flood Fill Algorithms in C# and GDI+](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/floodfillincsharp.aspx) and [Queue-Linear Flood Fill: A Fast Flood Fill Algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/queuelinearfloodfill.aspx).

And if you like to dig in the code and learn, there is the [Paint .Net](http://www.getpaint.net/) project that has an excelent flood fill implementation.