# Coloring non generic contours

Tags: c#, graphics

I am using C# and I am drawing the picture programmatically (since the picture can differ according to run time values of the parameters in my application). I end up with non generic closed contours (which consist of straight lines and curves). Now I need to fill those with different colors.
Any idea how can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does non-generic mean in this context?

Comment: Non-generic meaning nothing like ordinary polygons, circles, ellipsis...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [flood fill algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367226/flood-fill-algorithms). You're probably better off drawing to a bitmap, then rendering to the forms (I assume you're using WinForms).

Answer (score 0):

If it is Winforms I think best one is [FillRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillregion.aspx). Or try [Flood Fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230764/quickfill-flood-fill-algorithm-in-c-vb-net). Unfortunately this is not that easy because there no native Flood fill in .net. But there are free implementations and ways to import it from GDI

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PathGradientBrush` for this. [Here's a code example](https://web.archive.org/web/20121230094149/http://www.bobpowell.net/pgb.htm).

```
Public NotInheritable Class PathGradientBrush
          Inherits System.Drawing.Brush
     Member of System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Summary:
Encapsulates a System.Drawing.Brush object that fills the interior of a System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath object with a gradient. This class cannot be inherited.
```